# WPF DatagridComboboxcolumn not in combobox style

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

This has been a long problem of mine, and even though there are a lot of solutions out there, none has seemed to work for me.

How do I make the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` display as `Combobox` when it is not focused?
I tried using `DataGridTemplateColumn` and I've almost been successful in it except that when trying to identify the selected item in the `Combobox`, the value returns back to previous data, and honestly made it a lot harder for me to work on this compared to just using `DataGridComboBoxColumn`.

How can I do this without using `DataGridTemplateColumn`?
The `DataGrid` is found in a `UserControl` which is dynamically added to the MainWindow.

#### XAML

```xml
<!-- This is my preferred way-->
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header TagType x:Name="TagTypeCombo" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding TagType}"/>

<!--This is similar to all of solutions that I've seen-->
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Tag Type" x:Name="ComboTemplate">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox Width="135" x:Name="Tagger" ItemsSource="{Binding tagType,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=UserControl}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Tags}" SelectedValuePath="TagType"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

### Code-Behind

```cs
public int counter;
List<Tags> tags = new List<Tags>();
public event EventHandler SaveButtonClicked;
public List<string> tagType = new List<string>() { "Modbus Coil(0x)", "Discrete Input(1x)", "Input Register(3x)", "Holding Register(4x)" };
public ModbusCard2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
public class Tags
{
    public int TagAddress { get; set; }
    public string TagType { get; set; }
    public string TagID { get; set; }
}
private void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => ((WrapPanel)this.Parent).Children.Remove(this);
private void Tagger_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var cx = sender as ComboBox;
    cx.ItemsSource = tagType;
}
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= counter; i++)
    {
        tags.Add(new Tags() { TagAddress = 0, TagID = $"M{i}", TagType = "Discrete Input(1x)" });
    }
   DevTags.ItemsSource = tags;
}

private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SaveButtonClicked?.Invoke(sender, e);
}

private void EditButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => DevTags.IsReadOnly = false;

//For the SaveButtonClicked found in MainWindow
private void SaveButtonClicked(ModbusCard2 d)
{
    foreach (var a in d.DevTags.Items.OfType<Tags>().ToList())
    {
        if (a.TagType == d.tagType[1])
        {
            a.TagID = $"M{DICount}";
            DICount++;
        }
        if (a.TagType == d.tagType[2])
        {
            a.TagID = $"R{AICount}";
            AICount++;
        }
        d.DevTags.Items.Refresh();
    }
    d.DevTags.IsReadOnly = true;
}
```

Comment: The `DataGridTemplateColumn` is for sure your best bet here, but something's not behaving as intended. What do you mean when you say "the value returns back to previous data"? Is the ComboBox value changing back right after it loses focus, or is the bound value not updating?

Comment: Yes, the bound value is not updating. What happens in the program is that at first, it will generate a `DataGrid` and display an ID, a Tag Address, and the Tag Type. The last one is where the user can change the value using `ComboBox`. When the user is satisfied with their choice, it will look on each `ComboBox` per row to see what the user has chosen, then generate the proper ID per chosen Tag Type. Using `DataGridComboBoxColumn` this works fine, but when using `DataGridTemplateColumn` it reverts back to the initial value, which is giving me a headache right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with your `ComboBox` that's currently inside your `TemplateColumn`.

It adds logic in your binding to update your source trigger, while also removing your `SelectedValuePath` tag. I'm assuming based on your lack of a `DisplayMemberPath` tag that your `ComboBox` `ItemsSource` is a string collection. If this is the case the `SelectedValuePath` can actually wreck your bindings (I have no idea why though).

```
<ComboBox Width="135" x:Name="Tagger" ItemsSource="{Binding tagType,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=UserControl}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Tags, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Let me know if you still have binding update issues after, and will go from here.

Comment: Thank you very much. What I've tried is to set the Loaded Event for the `ComboBox` then added the `UpdateSourceTrigger`. I don't know why setting the `ItemsSource` directly in XAML doesn't work but setting it in Loaded event does. 
   `<ComboBox Width="135" x:Name="Tagger" Loaded="Tagger_Loaded" SelectedItem="{Binding TagType, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />`